# How can I write an xml file response to a rest-client GET to a file?

Tags: ruby, xml, marshalling, rest-client

There's a REST API for an app (SAS for Azure blob) that I am accessing via rest-client.

When I do:

```
response = RestClient.get "RESTURL"
```

I get back XML.

However, when I try to write the contents of response objects using:

```
marshal_dump = Marshal.dump(response)
file = File.new(file_name,'w')
file.write marshal_dump
file.close
```

I don't get a clean XML file.

How do I just take the XML output from the RestClient.get call and write it as an .xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's response.to_str:

```
File.open(file_name, 'w'){|f| f << response.to_str}
```